# ExtJS 4 MVC, Get Checkbox value integer instead of bool

Tags: json, extjs, checkbox, extjs4

I'm using a form to edit Model. I receive data in JSON. Here's my problem:
I receive data for Checkbox only in INT: 1 or 0, I cannot change it. JSON:

```
{ "checkboxValue": 1 }
```

This field in ExtJS model is defined as INT type. Model:

```
{name: "checkboxValue", type: Ext.data.Types.INT},
```

then I set values to form this way:

```
formCmp.loadRecord(loadedStore.getAt(0));
```

and my checkbox is set correctly: when I receive **1** it's checked, **0** - unchecked.

But when I try to save record and send data to server this way:

```
form.updateRecord(form.getRecord());
record.save();
```

I need Checkbox to have also INT value - 1 or 0. But it has only BOOL value - true or false so when JSON is sent that value is NaN.

```
{
    "checkboxValue": NaN
}
```

I think, that function `.updateRecord(..)` go through all elements and when it gets to checkbox it tries to get value, and the value is BOOL

Does anybody know how to make checkbox' output value INT?

Comment: You are correct in saying `updateRecord` makes it a bool because Ext sees your 1 or 0 as a bool... per the docs: **The main value of a checkbox is a boolean, indicating whether or not the checkbox is checked.**  So I would recommend either bypassing `updateRecord` and rolling your own validation, or trying to use [`inputValue`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-cfg-inputValue) somehow.  The fact that you get NaN in your JSON means something is failing anyway...

Comment: I think, I get NaN because model supposed to receive INT but receives true - BOOL. Tried to use `inputValue` but didn't work, anyway `Ext.getCmp('meCheckbox').getValue()` is only **true** or **false**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ext.form.Basic.updateForm uses getFieldValues method to retrieve new data for the updated record, while getFieldValues method returns only boolean values for checkboxes regardless of such properties as **inputValue** or **uncheckedValue**. So I would use convert function for the model's field to transform provided boolean value into an integer in a way like that:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'flag',
            type: 'int',
            convert: function (v, record) {
                return typeof v === 'boolean' ? (v === true ? 1 : 0) : v;
            }
        }
    ],
    ...
});
```

Here is a complete [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/triclozan/gDSVY/)

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be done with some simple overrides

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    bodyPadding: 10,
    width: 300,
    title: 'Pizza Order',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            fieldLabel: 'Toppings',
            defaultType: 'checkboxfield',
            items: [
                {
                    boxLabel  : 'Topping?',
                    name      : 'topping',
                    id        : 'checkbox1',

                    // include these two properties in your checkbox config
                    uncheckedValue: 0,
                    setValue: function(checked) {
                        var me = this;

                        arguments[0] = checked ? 1 : me.uncheckedValue;

                        me.callParent(arguments);

                        return me;
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: nice solution. Also can be applied in many others cases. Thanks